# CakePHP routing - search parms

Tags: cakephp, routes

I need to set up routing based on search parms (I'm using CakeDC search plugin)

URL should look like this: `/apartments/studio-apartments`

instead of this: `/apartments/propertytype_id:1`

I've already tried adding routes like this one:

```
Router::connect('/apartments/studio-apartments', array('controller'=>'apartments', 'action'=>'index'), array('pass'=>array('propertytype_id:1')));
```

or

```
Router::connect('/apartments/studio-apartments', array('controller' => 'apartments', 'action' => 'index', 'propertytype_id:1'));
```

or [that one](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration#Passing-parameters-to-action-949) from Cake book

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/apartments/studio-apartments',
    array('controller' => 'apartments','action' => 'index'),
    array('propertytype_id' => '[0-9\-]+')
);
```